# How can i make the copyrights and line at the left bottom of this pdf using latex code?

Tags: copyright

```
\begin{flushleft}

Copyright ^{c} 2011 Cleve Moler

MATLAB^{R} is a registered trademark of MathWorks, Inc.^{TM}

Octomber 4,2011

\end{flushleft}
```

I tried superscript but without the result i wanted,about the line i didn't find anything
[[image: Cleve Moler pdf]]

Comment: What exactly is your question or *this pdf*?

Comment: How can i make the line and the Trademarks show at the left bottom of the page exactly as is shown on the image i post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On only one or select pages, where you don't have a footer, I'd do this

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\copyrightFooter}{
  % Fill the rest of the page, so what comes below is on the bottom
  \vfill
  %Make a line
  \hrule
  %Make space after the line
  \vspace{\the\dimexpr\baselineskip/2}\relax
  %Make a group with small font size
  {
    \footnotesize
    \noindent Copyright~\textcopyright~2018 No One\\
    \texttt{SOFTWARE}\textsuperscript\textregistered
    is a registered trademark of Company CO\textsuperscript{TM}\\\today%
  }
}
\begin{document}
  Hello world!\copyrightFooter
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following footer:
[image]

---

If you want it on (almost) all pages, as part of the actual document footer, I'd use [`fancyhdr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr), like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\lfoot{%
  \footnotesize
  Copyright~\textcopyright~2018 No One\\
  \texttt{SOFTWARE}\textsuperscript\textregistered
  is a registered trademark of Company CO\textsuperscript{TM}\\\today%
 }
% Make a line at footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
% Remove line at header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
SomeText
\end{document}
```

Which produces this footer
[image]

### Addendum

A combination of the two would be to define a different `\fancypagestyle` that will just *add* the copyright if the style is invoked:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{copystyle}{
% Note the lack of \fancyhf{}, which makes this
% not clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[L]{%
  \footnotesize
  Copyright~\textcopyright~2018 No One\\
  \texttt{SOFTWARE}\textsuperscript\textregistered
  is a registered trademark of Company CO\textsuperscript{TM}\\\today%
 }
}
% Set default pagestyle
\pagestyle{fancy}
% Clear all header/footer
\fancyhf{}
% Write `My Document' in the bottom right footer
\rfoot{My Document}

% Make a line at footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
% Remove line at header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
  Only the `My Document' right footer is on this page
  \newpage
  % "Add" the copystyle on only this page
  \thispagestyle{copystyle}
  Here the `My Document' is still on the right footer in this page, but also
  the copyright text!
  \newpage
  This page does \emph{not} have the copyright text, but has the `My Document'
  in it's right footer.
\end{document}
```

The above will result in showing "My Document" in the right footer on *all* pages. The copyright, however, is now added/combined *only* on page 2 due to the `\thispagestyle{copystyle}`. The [fancyhdr documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) has more info :)

---

NB: I feel like with this copyright mark, I should address that this code falls under the licence as per described in [legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal). Which, at the time of writing, I believe is under the [Creative Commons CC-BY-SA](https://tldrlegal.com/license/creative-commons-attribution-sharealike-4.0-international-(cc-by-sa-4.0)).

Comment: Thank you so much!Now i get the result  but not in the specific page i want.It's shown at the beginning of the article i want it on specific page.How can i make this?

Comment: @theNewArtist oh, I thought you wanted it on every page. I’ll update it tomorrow:)

Comment: @theNewArtist Answer is now updated for one-page only :)

Comment: That does the trick!! Simply what you get is that where you call the function\copyrightFooter in your document you get the trademark under there.

Comment: Yes, @theNewArtist: Except if you have your own footer using e.g. `fancyhdr` (or just any other footer), because the `\copyrightFooter` will just push it to the bottom of the page, and the actual footer will be below that. In this case you could use the “addendum” part of the answer.